# Java will -classpath option add or replace CLASSPATH environment variable

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, environment-variables, jvm-arguments

Will the use of `-classpath` option with `java` add to or replace the contents of the `CLASSPATH` environment variable?

Comment: Good question. I've never thought about it

Comment: Do you want to know if the environment variable is changed?  Did you run a test to actually *see* if it changed?

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: @Zacky112, please note that running a jar file with the -jar option will ignore the CLASSPATH env variable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the classpath variable it overrides the CLASSPATH of Environment variable but only for that session. If you restart the application you need to again set the classpath variable.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks girienie for a concise answer. You must be a Java expert :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Quoted from the `java(1)` man page:

```
   -classpath classpath
   -cp classpath
          Specifies a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search  for  class  files.   Class
          path  entries  are separated by colons (:). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the
          CLASSPATH environment variable.

          If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the user class path consists of the cur-
          rent directory (.).
```

Comment: The environment variable is *not* updated at all, according to this.  I don't see how the answer is "yes".

Comment: @S.Lott - From whose point of view?  From the *program's* point of view the CLASSPATH value (if it exists) is replaced.  From the *shell's* point of view the CLASSPATH value isn't changed.  I think the original question was just badly worded.

Answer (score 8):

Either one of the options is used, not both.

> Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.

...

> The -classpath option is preferred because you can set it individually for each application without affecting other applications and without other applications modifying its value.

...

> Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

Comment: About the last point, is it still the case? When I run `java -cp tests Test.java`, it seems that it is still discovering classes from `.` (the present working directory).

Answer (score 8):

The usage of -cp option will not affect the CLASSPATH environment variable.

You can try this small code snippet to check this:

```
public class CPTest {
    public static void main (final String[] args) {
        String cp = System.getenv("CLASSPATH");
        System.out.println(cp);
    }
}
```

```
%echo $CLASSPATH  
/home/test/:.
```

The output without -cp option:

```
%java CPTest  
/home/test/:.
```

The output with -cp option:

```
%java -cp /home/xanadu:. CPTest  
/home/test/:.
```

The output is same for both invocations (one with -cp and one without).

Also either the path specified in the *CLASSPATH* environment variable is
used or the path specified with *-cp* option is used. It is not a mix of both 
it is one of them.

This is evident from the below invocation. 
If the CWD (current working directory **"."**)
is excluded from -cp option, the JVM launcher (i.e. java) cannot  find the
class file despite the CLASSPATH environment variable containing CWD (**"."**) in it.

```
%java -cp /home/test CPTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CPTest
```