# Add JARs to AppClassLoader in an Eclipse RCP Equinox app

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, classloader, java-11, equinox

I need to supply my own implementation of the ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory in an Eclipse RCP App.
I can do this with the
`Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=package.of.my.CustomForkJoinThreadFactory`
VM argument, so when the ForkJoinPool object gets instantiated it will look for my implemtation instead of the default thread factory.

The problem is, this is part of the JDK and it will try to load this class trough the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`, which is the `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader`. Since this is an Equinox Eclipse RCP app all the jars are Equinox bundles, and are in the EquinoxClassLoader, and the AppClassLoader only contains the Equinox launcher classes it need for startup.

Is there a way to add jars to the classpath of the AppClassLoader?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your ThreadFactory to the classpath using the `-classpath` jvm argument. See also [Java -classpath option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161468/java-classpath-option).

However this will not allow you to put the thread factory in an equinox bundle. You'd have to create a separate .jar for that.

Comment: The problem is, that eclipse generates a -classpath argument for itself, which points directly to the equinox launcher jar. If i set a a -classpath arg in the run configuration there will be 2 -classpath args. Do you happen to know from where that happens?